# Is refusing to give free water in a business establishment illegal?

Tags: business, human-rights, is-x-legal

I thought it was illegal to refuse free water to a patron, is this true in the United States? Does it vary from state to state?

Comment: As far as I know, it is never required to give free water. What might have given you the idea that such a law exists?

Comment: Global legal searches are generally too broad. There are millions of places on earth that can enact laws, and a comprehensive search of them is asking too much.

Comment: I just made the question more specific. I was given this idea by a close friend who said that a lawyer told them this.

Answer (score 1):

In NSW, Australia, premises licensed to sell alcohol for on-site consumption are required to have free tap water available for patrons. This doesn’t apply to other businesses.